# Change drop down selection using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to change the dropdown selection values of a webpage using PowerShell but had no luck.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-field input_controls">
    <div ng-non-bindable="" class="hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="sys_original.sc_task.state" name="sys_original.sc_task.state" value="2">
    </div>
    <select aria-required="false" aria-labelledby="label.sc_task.state" ng-non-bindable="true" name="sc_task.state" id="sc_task.state" onchange="onChange('sc_task.state');" style="; " class="form-control  ">
    <option value="" role="option" disabled="">-- None --</option>
    <option value="4" role="option" disabled="">Closed Incomplete</option>
    <option value="-5" role="option">Pending</option>
    <option value="-1" role="option" disabled="">Queued</option>
    <option value="1" role="option" disabled="">Open</option>
    <option value="2" selected="SELECTED" role="option">In Progress</option>
    <option value="7" role="option">Cancelled</option>
    <option value="3" role="option">Closed Complete</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I tried these in PowerShell:

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$IE.Visible= $TRUE


$StatusField = $IE.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("sc_task.state")
$StatusField.value = '-5'
$StatusField.fireEvent("onchange")
($StatusField | where {$_.innerHTML -eq "-5"}).Selected = $true
```

And it gives me the below errors:

```
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\...ps1:53 char:1
+ $StatusField.value = '-5'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\...ps1:54 char:1
+ $StatusField.fireEvent("onchange")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The property 'selected' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\....ps1:55 char:1
+ ($StatusField | where {$_.innerHTML -eq "-5"}).Selected = $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Please help.

Comment: You have not posted how `$IE` is defined. That seems to be a critical piece of information.

Comment: `$IE = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$IE.Visible= $TRUE`

I have been able to login into the website and modify some fields without any issue. I'm just stuck with this selection field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the dowpdown selection field was inside an iFrame due to which IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID was not working. I made the following change to my code and it is working fine now:

```
$StatusField = $IE.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('gsft_main').contentWindow.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('sc_task.state')
$StatusField.value = '-5'
```

Comment: Glad to hear you have solved the problem, congratulation.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the following code to use the querySelector and JQuery selectors to find the special option and select it.

**Edit**

If the select element is inside the iframe tag, we should first find the iframe, then, using the contentDocument and querySelector method to find the select element, like this:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange")
while ($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500}
$selectedvalue = "Volvo"
$ie.Document.getElementById("<iframe id attribute>").contentDocument.querySelector("#mySelect option[value=$selectedvalue]").selected = $true
$ie.Document.getElementById("<iframe id attribute>").contentDocument.getElementById("mySelect").FireEvent("onchange")
```

If not using Iframe control, you could use the following code:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("<the website url>")
while ($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500}
$selectedvalue = "1"
$ie.Document.getElementById("sc_task.state").querySelector("option[value='$selectedvalue']").selected = $true
$ie.Document.getElementById("sc_task.state").FireEvent("onchange")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @zhi-lv-MSFT but as the selection field was inside an iFrame this didn't help. I have shared the working code here.

Comment: hi kaz, I have modified the code,  it works well with your html elements, please check above code.